# Creating Stackdriver alerting policies via Monitoring v3 API

Tags: stackdriver

Using the Stackdriver v3 monitoring api, I can create monitoring groups, uptime checks, to include uptime checks based on the created monitoring groups, alerting policies, and uptime check alerting policies. The policies trigger as expected and I receive the configured notifications (notifications are configured manually via console UI).

I am using a combination of the API Explorer for REST methods and scripted, gcloud commands. The alerting policies are created using JSON files.

All is well except when viewing the Uptime Checks Overview UI > Policies (the little blue bell) from the Stackdriver console, every alerting policy created via the API has a grey bell, i.e. no association with an alerting policy (although all policies function as expected).

I’ve been at this for a while and I am out of ideas as to why. Has anyone observed this or possibly have any idea where the problem would be?

Comment: We could reproduce the same behavior.  It has been opened in [the public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/110544530) for further investigation . Unfortunately I can't provide any guarantee for the resolution timeline for now. Updates will be provided there.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the issue again. However, I couldn't. The Bell sign in Uptime Check UI seems to work as expected now. Thus, it seems the issue is fixed. You can follow its public tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/110544530).